# Using OpenVPN for specific application(s)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, openvpn

Is is possible to run Transmission or Google Chrome only using OpenVPN? Other applications should use default connection (eth0) since I am connected to Intranet which won't be accessible if all traffic is routed through VPN.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and some Premium VPN server (similar to [HMS VPN](https://hidemyass.com/vpn/))

Comment: Do you have an answer for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome - yes, you could setup a proxy on the other side and then a specific static route that says to access that proxy you must go via the OpenVPN tunnel. That would not be too hard to do.

For transmission you can look at setting up a SOCKS5 proxy.

This article explains how you can setup SSH to be a SOCKS5 proxy : http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/ . You then should be able to connect Chrome and Transmission to that. No need to worry about OpenVPN at all if you have ssh access to the box.

Comment: I don't know about SOCKS5 Proxy etc. What I do is start a openvpn client and connect to provided list of IP (with some settings and commands). 

Any detailed Guide/Link will be appreciated. :)